# React Meteor Data - Component Not Re-Rendering With New Data While Using withTracker

Tags: javascript, mongodb, reactjs, meteor, react-router

I'm using Meteor, React, react-meteor-data, and React Router. I am linking to a page and adding an /:id, which I am then trying to use to query the database and build out the component with the returned data.

The problem is the initial query returns an empty array. I can then see in my render method and componentWillReceiveProps that it returns the data I expect a moment later. The problem is that my component does not re-render. I am using withTracker because I want the component to update and re-render every time the database changes in the targeted Collection.

Here is the React code on the client-side:

```js
export default withTracker((props) => {
    const handle = Meteor.subscribe('game', props.match.params.id);
    return {
        listLoading: !handle.ready(),
        game: ActiveGames.find({ _id: props.match.params.id}).fetch(),
    };
})(Game);
```

And here is the publication in 'imports/api/activeGames.js':

```js
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';
import { check } from 'meteor/check';

export const ActiveGames = new Mongo.Collection('activeGames');

if (Meteor.isServer) {
   Meteor.publish('game', function (id) {
      check(id, String);
      return ActiveGames.find({ _id: id });
   });

   Meteor.publish('activeGames', function activeGamesPublication() {
      return ActiveGames.find();
   });
}
```

Here is a screenshot of the output I'm getting, with console logs to track the pertinent life cycle methods.

[image: Console Log of Component Loading]

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's a simple matter of doing something with the listLoading prop.
For instance, your Game component could be:

```
class Game extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }

  renderGames = () => {
    return this.props.games.map(g => {
      return (
        <li>{g.title}</li>
      )
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        {this.props.listLoading ? <span>Loading...</span> : this.renderGames()}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}

export default withTracker((props) => {
    const handle = Meteor.subscribe('game', props.match.params.id);
    return {
        listLoading: !handle.ready(),
        game: ActiveGames.find({ _id: props.match.params.id}).fetch(),
    };
})(Game);
```

This is how I handle the time between subscribing and receiving data.

Hope it helps, though I'm sure you found a solution by now ;)